# how to solve [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following problem, has anyone experienced a similar case and how to solve it.

```
E/flutter ( 5602): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 5602): #0      new Data.fromJson
package:siakad_masoem_university/models/transkrip_nilai.dart:188
E/flutter ( 5602): #1      new NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson.<anonymous closure>
package:siakad_masoem_university/models/transkrip_nilai.dart:120
E/flutter ( 5602): #2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:416:8)
E/flutter ( 5602): #3      new NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson
package:siakad_masoem_university/models/transkrip_nilai.dart:119
E/flutter ( 5602): #4      Services.getNilaiMahasiswa
package:siakad_masoem_university/provider/services.dart:128
E/flutter ( 5602): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5602): #5      _NilaiMahasiswaPageState.fetchData
package:siakad_masoem_university/…/akademik/transkrip_nilai.dart:62
E/flutter ( 5602): <asynchronous suspension>
```

and the error occurred when I changed the code here to do the addition

```
int getSum() {
                    final uts = data.first.nilaiIndeksUts;
                    final akhir = data.first.nilaiIndeksAkhir;
                    // int? uts = int.tryParse(data.first.nilaiIndeksUts ?? '');
                    // int? akhir = int.tryParse(data.first.nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '');
                    return (uts ?? 0) + (akhir ?? 0);
                  }
```

and this is when I call API data into list

```
fetchData(int smt) async {
    final apiResponse = await Services().getNilaiMahasiswa(smt);
    setState(() {
      data = (apiResponse.data!);
    });
  }
```

result when I display the result of the sum

```
Text(
                                      getSum().toString(),
                                      style: bold6,
                                    ),
```

this is when i do the API call

```
Future<NilaiMahasiswa> getNilaiMahasiswa(int semester) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/transkrip_nilai?semester=$semester',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

and this is from the API data that has been converted into the model

```
class NilaiMahasiswa {
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Data>? data;

  NilaiMahasiswa({this.status, this.code, this.data});

  NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['code'] = code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? idTranskripNilai;
  String? idMk;
  String? kodeMk;
  String? nmMk;
  int? sks;
  int? smt;
  String? nilaiAkhirUts;
  String? nilaiHurufUts;
  int? nilaiIndeksUts; // convert it to int the moment you receive the data
  String? nilaiAkhirUas;
  String? nilaiAkhir;
  String? nilaiHurufAkhir;
  int? nilaiIndeksAkhir; // convert it to int the moment you receive thedata
  int? statusNilaiAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiUts;
  String? updatedBy;
  int? summationResult;

  Data(
      {this.idTranskripNilai,
      this.idMk,
      this.kodeMk,
      this.nmMk,
      this.sks,
      this.smt,
      this.nilaiAkhirUts,
      this.nilaiHurufUts,
      this.nilaiIndeksUts,
      this.nilaiAkhirUas,
      this.nilaiAkhir,
      this.nilaiHurufAkhir,
      this.nilaiIndeksAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiUts,
      this.updatedBy});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idTranskripNilai = json['id_transkrip_nilai'];
    idMk = json['id_mk'];
    kodeMk = json['kode_mk'];
    nmMk = json['nm_mk'];
    sks = json['sks'];
    smt = json['smt'];
    nilaiAkhirUts = json['nilai_akhir_uts'];
    nilaiHurufUts = json['nilai_huruf_uts'];
// converting to int
    nilaiIndeksUts = int.tryParse(json['nilai_indeks_uts']);
    nilaiAkhirUas = json['nilai_akhir_uas'];
    nilaiAkhir = json['nilai_akhir'];
    nilaiHurufAkhir = json['nilai_huruf_akhir'];
// converting to int
    nilaiIndeksAkhir = int.tryParse(json['nilai_indeks_akhir']);
    statusNilaiAkhir = json['status_nilai_akhir'];
    statusNilaiUts = json['status_nilai_uts'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
    summationResult = nilaiIndeksAkhir! + nilaiIndeksUts!;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id_transkrip_nilai'] = this.idTranskripNilai;
    data['id_mk'] = this.idMk;
    data['kode_mk'] = this.kodeMk;
    data['nm_mk'] = this.nmMk;
    data['sks'] = this.sks;
    data['smt'] = this.smt;
    data['nilai_akhir_uts'] = this.nilaiAkhirUts;
    data['nilai_huruf_uts'] = this.nilaiHurufUts;
    data['nilai_indeks_uts'] = this.nilaiIndeksUts;
    data['nilai_akhir_uas'] = this.nilaiAkhirUas;
    data['nilai_akhir'] = this.nilaiAkhir;
    data['nilai_huruf_akhir'] = this.nilaiHurufAkhir;
    data['nilai_indeks_akhir'] = this.nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_akhir'] = this.statusNilaiAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_uts'] = this.statusNilaiUts;
    data['updated_by'] = this.updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your api response. Probably you are trying to add a null response from your api to your data model. If you try to parse a null value to string, you will probably see that error.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
Class Data {
  Data(this.idTranskripNilai, this.idMk, …)

  final String idTranskripNilai;
  final String idMk;
  …

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final String? idTranskripNilai = json["id_transkrip_nilai"];
    final String? idMk = json["id_mk"];
    …

    return Data(
      idTranskripNilai ?? "",
      idMk ?? "",
      …
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id_transkrip_nilai'] = this.idTranskripNilai;
    data['id_mk'] = this.idMk;
    data['kode_mk'] = this.kodeMk;
    data['nm_mk'] = this.nmMk;
    data['sks'] = this.sks;
    data['smt'] = this.smt;
    data['nilai_akhir_uts'] = this.nilaiAkhirUts;
    data['nilai_huruf_uts'] = this.nilaiHurufUts;
    data['nilai_indeks_uts'] = this.nilaiIndeksUts;
    data['nilai_akhir_uas'] = this.nilaiAkhirUas;
    data['nilai_akhir'] = this.nilaiAkhir;
    data['nilai_huruf_akhir'] = this.nilaiHurufAkhir;
    data['nilai_indeks_akhir'] = this.nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_akhir'] = this.statusNilaiAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_uts'] = this.statusNilaiUts;
    data['updated_by'] = this.updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: does the dot (...) follow the above

and replaced everything to be final?

Comment: Yes, I didn't write all the fields, I just gave two fields as an example

Comment: ok i will try..

Comment: the following error message occurs
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h_ImBQjw8nD9SZ8JCSTnO8GwYEtIAM6T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, that was my code error. I edited

Comment: just one more error
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJZ6skoaITN1E2f9YbLGuwjUhbjvsfE2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you use the code at the top of my code (`final String idTranskripNilai;`)?

Comment: Oh, there is a problem. I edited

Comment: I have followed according to what you provided but there are still errors, maybe you can check it here
https://pastebin.com/Ajesx9Z3

Comment: Replace `final string? idTranskripNilai;` to `final String idTranskripNilai;`, others do the same

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vod1s86xyQzNRnzAsHTsZcq2HUH1jjza/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Remove `{` and `}`

Comment: there are no more errors in the model, but it still gives the same error message.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250543/discussion-between-sharon-and-my-car).